# How to Configure CIDER repl?

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

The markdown for CIDER about configuring the CIDER repl starts off by saying:

> You can certainly use CIDER without configuring it any further, but here are some ways other folks are adjusting their CIDER experience.

And then list several expressions like `(setq nrepl-log-messages t)`. But where do those expressions need to be written to??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These examples go in a file called (assuming linux or mac)

```
~/.emacs.d/init.el
```

It's also worth knowing about the [emacs live](https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live) starter package which already includes a decently configured cider amongst a bunch of other stuff. I publish my much smaller [config](https://github.com/thearthur/arthur-s-emacs-config) here if you're interested in something closer to the defaults or just want more examples.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using CIDER (maintained by [Bozhidar Batsov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/291550/bozhidar-batsov)), then also check out his own project for setting up emacs called [Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude). It's an alternative to emacs live (as pointed out by Arthur).

I've used both, but switched to Prelude as the CIDER updates tend to be more tightly matched as versions change due to it being the same author.

Answer (score 0):

Another good 'canned' configuration is Purcell's emacs.d. It has a good initial cider and clojure configuration. I also found it was easier to modify/update and (for me anyway) I found it easier to understand, which means easier to fix when something doesn't quite work the way you want. One of the big drawbacks with some of these canned emacs configurations is that you don't get to understand how they work and then when they break, your lost until the author or someone else fixes it. I found Purcell's version was a nice complete setup, but one I was able to easily modify to better fit my needs. Tweaking emacs to fit your needs rather than tweaking yourself to meet the needs of the editor is possibly the greatest strength of emacs and why people end up loving it. Unfortunately, it can also be a PITA when all you want to do is start coding!

See http://www.github.com/purcell/emacs.d.git